# React setState not re-rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components, setstate

I got the following react code

```
const [folders, setFolders] = useState([
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'name',
        logo: 'logo',
        tasks: 
        [ 
            {
                id: 1,
                text: 'blaas bla bla',
                done: true,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                text: 'bla bla bla',
                done: false,
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'name',
        logo: 'logo',
        tasks: 
        [ 
            {
                id: 3,
                text: 'blasdasda bla bla',
                done: true,
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                text: 'bla bla bla',
                done: false,
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'naasdme',
        logo: 'logo',
        tasks: 
        [ 
            {
                id: 5,
                text: 'bla bla bla',
                done: false,
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                text: 'bla bla bla',
                done: false,
            },
        ]
    }
    ]);

function deleteTask( taskId )
{
    setFolders((prev) =>
    {
        prev.forEach( (folder) => 
        {
            folder.tasks = folder.tasks.filter( task => task.id != taskId )
        })
        return prev;
    });
}
```

The code works great it do update the state but the component not re render.

I'm using the component with Declarative Routing and I tried few ways to do that to check if the problem is in the routing but probably not.

```
<Route path='/Tasks/:id' render={(props) => 
                    (
                        <Tasks {...props} folders={folders} onDelete={deleteTask} updateTask= {updateTask} />
                    )}
                />
                <Route path='/Tasks/:id' > 
                    <Tasks folders={folders} onDelete={deleteTask} updateTask={updateTask} />
                </Route>

                <Route path='/Tasks/:id' children={<Tasks folders={folders} onDelete={deleteTask} 
 updateTask={updateTask} /> } />
```

All those 3 ways works just fine.

Any suggestion way the component not rerender?

Comment: Replace forEach to map and return mapped array.

Comment: The same problem it change but it is not re rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  const deleteTask = (taskId) =>
    setFolders((prev) =>
      prev.map(({ tasks, ...rest }) => ({
        ...rest,
        tasks: tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== taskId),
      }))
    );
```

Working example:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [folders, setFolders] = React.useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "name",
      logo: "logo",
      tasks: [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: "blaas bla bla",
          done: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: "bla bla bla",
          done: false,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "name",
      logo: "logo",
      tasks: [
        {
          id: 3,
          text: "blasdasda bla bla",
          done: true,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          text: "bla bla bla",
          done: false,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "naasdme",
      logo: "logo",
      tasks: [
        {
          id: 5,
          text: "bla bla bla",
          done: false,
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          text: "bla bla bla",
          done: false,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  const deleteTask = (taskId) =>
    setFolders((prev) =>
      prev.map(({ tasks, ...rest }) => ({
        ...rest,
        tasks: tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== taskId),
      }))
    );

  return folders.map((folder) => (
    <div>
      <h1>{folder.title}</h1>
      {folder.tasks.map((task) => (
        <div>
          <p>{task.text}</p>
          <button onClick={() => deleteTask(task.id)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ));
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Your solution return task array instead of folder array.

Comment: Error, probably setstate asynchronous.

Comment: after you edited your answer it worked! thank you man

Comment: No problem, thanks to the @KirillSkomarovskiy.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I’m from phone.

```js
const deleteTask = (taskId) =>
  setFolders((prev) =>
    prev.map(({ tasks, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, tasks: tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== taskId) })
  );
```

Comment: This is the right answer, I copy this in my answer too.

Comment: @b3hr4d your stolen my code and get right answer. .

Answer (score 0):

You should use `map` instead of `forEach` because map returns a new array. The component does not re-render, because you modify the array `folders`, but you don't change the reference. React does not consider that the state is changed, because the value it reads (the reference of the array «its starting point in memory») is not changed.

Comment: The same problem it changes the state but it is not re rendering.